# How do I grep for a string excluding some other string

Tags: grep, sh

I want to do sth like:

```
grep -A 10 'myString' && NOT 'anotherString'
```

If I didn't need `-A 10` I know I could pipe greps and use `-v`, but it would not work like that in this case. So I would do sth like that:

```
grep "myString" | grep -v "anotherString"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to invert and place the grep with the -A 10 argument in the end. Like this:

```
grep -v 'anotherString' | grep -A 10 'myString'
```

Answer (score 0):

The only POSIX supported options for `grep` are -EFcefilnqsvx so be aware that the `-A` option may not be present on all implementations of `grep`. And even on GNU `grep` there is no option to specify "match OR match" and there is no regex that can emulate this as all it can do is provide additional matches, but can not withhold them. Essentially the only way to accomplish this with `grep` alone is to use a pipe.